# iOS 4.0 AudioMix and AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

Problem: Trying to create a Mix that is applied to the AVPlayerItem, but it crashes with ECX_BAD_ACCESS the moment it hits setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:

Code:

```
AVMutableAudioMix *fadeMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters alloc];
[params setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0.0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(0, 1), CMTimeMake(60, 1))];
[fadeMix setInputParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:params]];
```

I have to assume the problem lies in the CMTimeRangeMake, though most examples I saw (as scarce as they are to find) did things similarly.

Basically I am just trying to create a simple fade out that lasts one minute and progressively goes from 100% to 0%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am silly, it was supposed to be

```
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
```

Not

```
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *params = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters alloc];
```